# Laravel API store and retrieve base64 images in Storage

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with Angular and Laravel on a project where I have `destinations` table

And I need to store destinations, and for every destination there is multiple images I need to store

So there is `destination_images` table, I made one-to-many relationship between the tables

So I have two models: `Destination` - `DestinationImage`

The store Laravel function

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:100',
        'description' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return response()->json($errors);
    }

    $destination = Destination::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description
    ]);

    foreach ($request->fileSource as $img_code) {
        $ext = explode('/', mime_content_type($img_code))[1];
        $img_name = uniqid() . ".$ext";
        $decoded_img = base64_decode($img_code);
        $path = Storage::put('uploads/destinations' . $img_name, $decoded_img);
        DestinationImage::create([
            'destination_id' => $destination->id,
            'img' => $img_name
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json('Destination Added Successfully');
}
```

and it stores the file successfully but now I need to retrieve the images from Laravel storage and show it in Angular so I made this function

```
public function view($id) {
    $destination = Destination::findOrFail($id);

    $destination_images = $destination->destination_images;

    foreach ($destination_images as $destination_image) {
        $url = Storage::url($destination_image->img);

        return response()->json($url);
    }
}
```

but the response is not completed url it's just `"/storage/62a7056a5d8c6.png"`

Please anyone can help me how to maintain the view function to show the images in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You are using storage path mean while client can't access to it.
First you need to enable storage link `php artisan storage:link` and it should able to access http://yourdomain.com/storage/62a7056a5d8c6.png

---

```
$image = App\Models\DestinationImage::find(1);

echo url("/destination_images/{$image->id}");
```

---

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function view($id) {
    $destination = Destination::findOrFail($id);

    $destination_images = $destination->destination_images;
    $imageList = [];


    foreach ($destination_images as $destination_image) {
        $imageList[] = Storage::url($destination_image->img);

        return response()->json($imageList);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro, but when I tested this URL in browser it said 404 Not Found
http://localhost:8080/rindex/storage/62a7056a5d8c6.png
I made sure that the file exists successfully